# API openweathermap.org. Как показывать погоду конкретного города, берущегося из массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вот компонент, отвечающий за запросы на сервер:
[image: запрос на сервер]

Вот компонент отвечающий за рендер:[image: рендер]

Что хочу получить: выбираю город из селектора - соответсвенно рендерится прогноз погоды по этому городу.
Вопрос. Какой аргумент мне прописывать в getWeather()? city нельзя это просто весь массив. city[0] тоже, т.к. получает жестко привязанный элемент, мне то надо динамически.
И второй вопрос. Как правильно реализовать логику в этом компоненте?

```
    <div className="search_city">
        <select name="select"> 
            {city.map(item => <option value={item}>{item}</option>)}
        </select>
    </div>
```

Если я оставляю так, то получается незадействованный "tawn" из useState.
В общем не хватает знаний (или я просто сильно туплю), что бы дожать функционал, прошу помощи.
p.s.
Результат на выходе такой (не смотрите на стили потом доделаю).
[image: результат]

Температуру, ветер и т.д. разбил на отдельные компоненты, вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
@gaf, получается вот так:

```
const SearchCity = () => {

const {getWeather} = WeatherServise();

const city = [
    {
      "id": "833",
      "name": "Ḩeşār-e Sefīd"
    },
    {
        "id": '3245',
        "name": "Taglag",
    },
]

const [tawn, setTawn] = useState('Voronezh');

useEffect(() => {
    updateId();
}, [])

const updateId = () => {
    getWeather(tawn)
        .then(onWeatherLoaded)   
} 

const onWeatherLoaded = (e) => {
    setTawn(e.target.value);
}

return (
    <div className="search_city">
        <select value={tawn} onChange = {onWeatherLoaded} name="select"> 
            {city.map(item => <option 
                key = {item.id}>
                {item.name}</option>)}
        </select>
    </div>
)   
}
```

В консоли получаю ошибку:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
Плюс я не понимаю куда и зачем мне нужно поднимать состояние, у меня все отрисовывается в этом компоненте

Answer (score 1):

**Сначала:** Тебе нужно почитать что такое ["Контролируемые компоненты"](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/forms.html#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) - это ответит сразу на оба вопроса: как подгружать динамически и как правильно реализовать логику.

**Потом:** `tawn` - это ответ с данными о погоде. Значит должен его передавать туда, где ты отрисовываешь данные, тебе их надо поднять выше из компонента `SearchCity`, для этого почитай про ["Подъём состояния"](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). В будущем можешь почитать про ["Контекст"](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - это более продвинутый подход к этой задаче.

**И наконец:** После того, как разберешься со всем предыдущим: тебе не нужно делать запрос `getWeather()` в `Temperature`, теперь можешь просто получить данные от родительского компонента через `props` и отрисовать их.

***Обновление в ответ на изменение вопроса***:

```
const SearchCity = () => {

const { getWeather } = WeatherServise();  

const city = [
    {
      "id": "833",
      "name": "Ḩeşār-e Sefīd"
    },
    {
        "id": '3245',
        "name": "Taglag",
    },
]

const [town, setTown] = useState('Taglag') // Это имя текущего города и функция для его обновления. Начальное значение Taglag

useEffect(() => {
    const getWeatherData = async () => {
        const data = await getWeather(town) // Вернется массив с данными о погоде, тебе надо его передать таким компонентам, как: Temperature, чтобы они отрисовывали новые данные       
    }
    getWeatherData()
}, [town]) // <- Запрос выполняем каждый раз, когда пользователь выбирает новый город

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTown(e.target.value)
}

return (
    <div className="search_city">
        <select value={town} onChange = {handleChange}>  /* Это value значит какое значение сейчас выбрано */ 
            {city.map(item => <option 
                key={item.id}
                value={item.name}  /* Это value значит вариант, который можно выбрать, не забывай указывать */
             >
                {item.name}</option>)}
        </select>
    </div>
    )
}
```